# Stopping postgresql from starting on ubuntu startup

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu, service

Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
I have tried:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f postgresql remove
```

and

```
sudo vim /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/start.conf
```

then i change the word "auto" to "disabled"

Then i reboot the computer, and when it starts, i login and do:

```
sudo service --status-all | grep postgresql
```

Which returns:

```
[ + ]  postgresql
```

So it is still starting when the server starts.
What is left for me to do? I don't want this service running when the computer starts, only when i manually start it with:

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

Comment: See the SystemD section here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services

Comment: Thank you. I don't know which solution fixed it, but it's fixed now. It won't let me mark a best answer.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 167):

Use systemctl command to manage postgresql service:

1. stop service:

   `systemctl stop postgresql`
2. start service:

   `systemctl start postgresql`
3. show status of service:

   `systemctl status postgresql`
4. disable service(not auto-start any more)

   `systemctl disable postgresql`
5. enable service postgresql(auto-start)

   `systemctl enable postgresql`

Comment: The service still auto-starts after a `sudo systemctl disable postgresql@10-main`. `sudo service postgresql@10-main disable` doesn't work, either. Perhaps editing `/etc/postgresql/10/main/start.conf` might do the trick.

Comment: I tried disabling it.. but I'm getting a permission denied error.. @g10guang  - need to add sudo!

Comment: It really helped me out. It works perfectly.

Comment: on ubuntu 20.04.5 i needed to edit /etc/postgresql/[VERSION]/main/start.conf and change auto -> disabled

Answer (score 14):

Ok. it's fixed thanks to Koen De Groote.

I did:

```
echo manual | sudo tee /etc/init/postgresql.override
```

and

```
sudo systemctl disable postgresql.service
```

and

```
sudo systemctl disable postgresql
```

....I don't know which one of them did it, but its not starting any more... Thank you...

Comment: @asdf `sudo systemctl disable postgresql` this is enough.